# Добавление .ico 16x16 на сайт в меню html

Tags: css, html5

Как добавить иконку в менюшку на сайт? Как на картинке точки перед: новости, пресса и.т.д [image: меню]

Что можно добавить в код чтоб появились иконки перед каждой ссылкой в меню?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого нужно установить свойство `list-style-image:` для списка. Это свойство как раз определяет изображение, которое будет использоваться в качестве маркера.

Пример страницы с подобным списком

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <style>
   ul {
    list-style-image: url(images/marker.png); /* здесь указываете путь к картинке */
   }
  </style>
 </head> 
 <body> 
 <ul>
    <li>Новости</li>
    <li>Пресса</li>
    <li>Анкета</li>
 </ul>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Помогло!)